# JS can't serialize an array

Tags: javascript

It's 1st time i faced it. How to serialize an array? I tried but my code doesn't work.

```
   var shop_cartids = ["Hi","Hello", "Bonjour"];    
   alert( shop_cartids.serializeArray());
```

Comment: What led you to believe that method exists at all?

Comment: Serialize to which format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
var shop_cartids = ["Hi","Hello", "Bonjour"];    
alert(JSON.stringify(shop_cartids));
```